# How to get list of the sql server localdbs installed on am windows 10

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to clean up my machine and I wanted to uninstall all the unused software.

i know there are two versions of sql express isntalled on my machine and wanted to knwo if there are any other sql server express versions sittling on my machine?

I've tried to search services from services.msc and I could not find any.

What are the other ways I can get list of installed sql servers ?

Comment: I've also tried fo fidn sqlserver.exe from the task manager and then I've searched for this file on my c:\ drive and I found 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

check out this script:

```
DECLARE @radhe TABLE
( x nvarchar(100),
 InstanceNames nvarchar(100),
 Data nvarchar(100))

Insert into @radhe
EXECUTE xp_regread
  @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
  @key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server',
  @value_name = 'InstalledInstances'

Select * from @radhe
```

I have 2 instances on this server (`sql server 2016`) and it shows it like this:

[image]